# Removing disabled from checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, disabled-input

I have 2 checkboxes styled as toggle buttons.
The 2nd checkbox is by default `disabled`.
When the 1st checkbox is to ja I would like the 2nd checkbox to have `disabled` removed.

I have tried this with 2 codes but I did not succeed.
In my console I see no errors.

[image]

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="email_user" name="email_user" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small" data-on="Ja" data-off="Nee" onclick="remove_disabled()">
    Verstuur melding ook per e-mail naar collega.
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="email_relatie" name="email_relatie" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small" data-on="Ja" data-off="Nee" disabled>
    Verstuur een kopie van deze melding naar de relatie.
  </label>
</div>
```

**Option 1**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function remove_disabled() {
    document.getElementById('email_relatie').disabled = false;
}
</script>
```

**Option 2**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function remove_disabled() {
    document.getElementById('email_relatie').removeAttr('disabled')
}
</script>
```

Comment: I would guess the click event is being absorbed by the style plugin (maybe through `event.stopPropagation()`). You might want to try changing the event binding to "onchange" instead. Also, please create a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? because I tested option 1 and it worked.

Comment: Where do you put your script because the first option works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/kj4rxfy9/1/.  Are you clicking the label and not the actual checkbox?

Comment: Are you including your script in your page *before* your radio buttons?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t6upravz/  This logic works fine, provided the script is above the markup for the checkboxes, since you are using inline bindings.

Comment: You could also do something like an onChange, then you could say if the value of the checkbox is "ja" to remove the attribute, otherwise it is "nee" and you want it disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, `document.getElementById("email_relatie").disabled = false;` works just fine. Just use the `change` handler and check if the checkbox is checked or not:

```js
function remove_disabled() {
  if(document.getElementById("email_user").checked)
    document.getElementById("email_relatie").disabled = false;
  else 
    document.getElementById("email_relatie").disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="email_user" name="email_user" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small" data-on="Ja" data-off="Nee" onchange="remove_disabled()">
    Verstuur melding ook per e-mail naar collega.
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="email_relatie" name="email_relatie" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small" data-on="Ja" data-off="Nee" disabled>
    Verstuur een kopie van deze melding naar de relatie.
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Sure, you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want the checkbox to be disabled again once the first checkbox is unchecked, otherwise your given code would work. You can achieve this by setting the disabled attribute to false when the first checkbox is checked, and true when it is not.

```js
function toggle_disabled() {
    document.getElementById('email_relatie').disabled = !document.getElementById('email_user').checked;
}
```

```html
 <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="email_user" name="email_user" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small" data-on="Ja" data-off="Nee" onclick="toggle_disabled()">
    Verstuur melding ook per e-mail naar collega.
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="email_relatie" name="email_relatie" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small" data-on="Ja" data-off="Nee" disabled>
    Verstuur een kopie van deze melding naar de relatie.
  </label>
</div>
Option 1
```

Answer (score 0):

have you try ?

`<input type="checkbox" ... disabled="disabled">`

`document.getElementById('email_relatie').removeAttr('disabled');`

Answer (score -1):

You can use do like this:

```
$("input[name='email_relatie']").prop("disabled", false);
```

Comment: This is the same as `domElement.disabled = false` that they have in their first example.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks for the feedback! It has skipped by me while checking.

Answer (score -2):

Use the `.prop()`

```
$("[type='checkbox']").prop("disabled", false);
```

Comment: This is the same as `domElement.disabled = false` that they have in their first example.